# Micsoft visual studio2005

Tags: user-interface

what is the difference Managed GUI and unmanaged(native) GUI?
I want to do GUI for both elevator control and camera contol, which one is preferable to make GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Read this wikipedia article on managed code:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code

I would recommend managed code since you are asking what the difference is. Managed code takes care of deleting heap variables and niceties like that (assuming you are using C++).